# Are the RFC3526 MODP groups Schnorr groups?

Tags: diffie-hellman, prime-numbers, group-theory

I was wondering if a group like the 1536-bit MODP Group from [RFC 3526](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3526.txt) was a 
[Schnorr group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schnorr_group)?

A Schnorr group must apparently have:

- $p$ and $q$ being primes
- $p = q\cdot r+1$
- $1 < h < p$
- $h^r\not\equiv 1\pmod p$

And then $g = h^r\bmod p$ is the generator.

In RFC3526's 1536-bit MODP, there's a prime:
$$2^{1536}-2^{1472}-1+2^{64}\cdot\lfloor2^{1406}\cdot\text{pi}+741804\rfloor$$
<sup>(not too sure what $\text{pi}$ is here)</sup>
and the generator is $g=2$.

My question is if such a group is a Schnorr group or not?

If it's a Schnorr group, what are the values or $p$, $q$, $r$ and $h$?

References:
[RFC3526 MODP Diffie-Hellman groups for IKE](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3526.txt)
[en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schnorr_group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schnorr_group)

Comment: I'd guess these are safe primes, so $r=2$, for Schnorr groups we generally select a much smaller $q$, only twice the security level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it meets the formal definition of a Schnorr group; however it was constructed somewhat differently.  Normally, when we generate a Schnorr group, we pick a prime $q$, and then search for an $r$ so that $qr+1$ is also prime; with the RFC3526 group, they picked $p$ and $q$ simultaneously.  In addition, when it came to selecting the generator, they did not select the value $h$ and compute $g$ from that.  Instead, they selected $p$ such that $g=2$ generated a prime subgroup.

As for the values you asked about:

$$p = 2^{1536} - 2^{1472} - 1 + 2^{64} * \lfloor 2^{1406} \pi + 741804 \rfloor$$

(and yes, $pi = \pi$ is everyone's favorite transcendental number)

$$q = (p-1)/2$$

$$r = 2$$

$$h = 2^{(p+1)/4} \bmod p$$

We have this rather odd looking $h$ because that makes $h^r \equiv 2$.  Since Schnorr groups had no restriction on what $h$ is (other than $h^r \not\equiv 1$), this satisfies the definition.

Comment: thanks, this really helps me a lot... I thought it was a Schnorr group, but I couldn't understand how the generator could possibly be 2.

Answer (score 1):

While MODP groups such as the question's one meet the definition of Schnorr groups (as explained in the [other answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/15820/555)), we'd normally not call them Schnorr groups. By analogy, we'd normally not call $42$ a complex number.

MODP groups belong to a very special subclass of Schnorr groups: they use $p=2q+1$ with $q$ prime, maximizing the order of $h$ (with that restricted to be prime). Use of $p$ with this special form (called safe primes) predate the notion of Schnorr group. These are named after the publication of Claus-Peter Schnorr, [*Efficient Identification and Signatures for Smart Cards*](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/0-387-34805-0_22.pdf), in [proceedings of Crypto 1989](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-46885-4_68). He exposed groups devised so that the prime order $q$ of generator $h$ is much shorter than $p$, allowing shorter signatures. That's what we'd normally expect from a Schnorr group, and that's not met by a MODP group.

Further, the MODP groups of [RFC 2409](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2409#section-6) and [RFC 3526](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3526#section-6) use $p$ of the special form
$$p=2^{64k}-2^{64k-64}-1+2^{64}\bigl\lfloor 2^{64k-130}\pi+s_k\bigr\rfloor$$
for some integer $k$, and $s_k$ the smallest integer such that $q=(p-1)/2$ is prime and $2^q\bmod p\ne1$. This insures that

- $h=2$ can be used as a generator of prime order (that's the prescribed generator).
- The number of consecutive high-order bits set in $p$ is $66$, which simplifies estimation of quotient digits in Euclidean division with base $2^{64}$ (or smaller powers of two) while not overly simplifying Discrete Logarithm computation with [SNFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_number_field_sieve).
- The low-order $64$ bits are set, which simplifies Montgomery arithmetic in base $2^{64}$.

Comment: In principle one could search for primes of the same shape, with the only difference being that one test for the criterion that $p$ has a 256-bit prime factor $q$ instead of a $\lfloor\lg p\rfloor$-bit prime factor $q$.  Obviously, then there's little significance to $g = 2$, but one would get a Schnorr group with all the other consequences of the RFC 2412 criteria you described.